# Why is a load in a digital circuit capacitive?

Tags: capacitor, digital-logic

I know that the output load in a digital circuit is a capacitor. But why is that so?

For example, the output load of a simple AND gate is represented by a capacitor.

I think the load should be represented by a resistor.

Comment: What circuit? What load? This is a very unclear question and I'd vote to close if I had enough rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question needs polishing. I presume you're talking about HCMOS ICs connected to other HCMOS.

The input of a HCMOS circuit is usually a couple of MOSFETs (one NMOS, one PMOS). The gate of a MOSFET leaks only a very tiny current. In most logic ICs and microcontrollers it's specified as 1\$\mu\$A maximum, usually it's far less than that. That means the resistive load is negligible; an HCMOS output can drive hundreds of inputs.

But the gates also have a capacitance, usually a couple to a few tens of pF. In practice this is more important than the resistive load, since the limited drive current of an output has to charge/discharge one or more of these capacitors. In high-speed systems, if there are many of them connected to an output the delay this causes may be significant.

Connecting a larger capacitor directly to the output of an HCMOS IC is not a good idea; the output transistors don't like the high current peak when the output state changes.

I've never seen this capacitive load drawn in a schematic, however. Can you upload the schematic where you've seen this?

Comment: @shampa - The gate is insulated from the channel it controls. It lies as a small surface against it, so if there's a voltage difference between the gate and the channel it will act as one plate of a parallel-plate capacitor.

Comment: I have seen the load represented by a cap whenever I was studying VLSI design at a university.

Answer (score 2):

A capacitive load is one which, if the voltage on one changes relative to the other, will allow some electrons to flow "through" it in response to that voltage change.  To understand why this behavior occurs, imagine that one has two metal plates close together, connected via wires to other equipment which is sufficiently far away that electrostatic forces between the plates and anything else will be negligible.  Assume both plates start at the same voltage (electric potential).

If a voltage is placed between the leads, this will immediately cause electrons to flow from the more negative terminal into its plate, and from the other plate to the more positive terminal.  If the plates did not interact with each other, the number of electrons that would flow before the increased "pressure" on the positive plate and "vacuum" on the negative plate equaled the potential difference on the wires would be very small.  As it happens, however, when the plates start having a potential difference between them, the electrons in the negative-connected plate flock toward the edge near the positive plate, thus making room for more electrons elsewhere on the plate.  Likewise, the edge of the positive plate which is nearest the negative plate will have its electrons pushed away by those of the negative plate, thus increasing the "pressure" elsewhere on the plate and increasing electrons' willingness to leave.

Note that there are limits to the aforementioned effects; as more electrons are pushed into one plate and pulled from the other, the amount of "back-pressure" that isn't canceled by the plates' reactions to each other will increase.  Nonetheless, the number of electrons that can be seemingly pushed "through" the plates will exceed by many orders of magnitude the amount that could be pushed into one plate or pulled from the other in the absence of the aforementioned interaction.  Note also that increasing the surface area of the plates, or decreasing the distance between them, will enhance these effects.

Modern digital circuits have lots of connected elements in very close proximity to each other.  Transistors operate by using electric charges in a portion called the "gate" to draw electrons to the near side of a portion called the "channel" (allowing conduction) or push them out of it (stopping conduction).  The same types of physical characteristics that make transistors work well (increasing surface area, and decreasing distance) also increase the extent to which they allow some electrons to seemingly flow through them any time the potential across them changes.